# Streaming over Janus using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, janus-gateway

> I've ran Janus on a server and it works fine, but I'm kind of
> struggling finding a way to stream on the Janus server, I could not
> find any snippet code out there, I am developing with Vue.js, is there
> any library to stream over Janus? I just need a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Janus Gateway has a streaming plugin. You need to enable the plugin and use some software like gstreamer or ffmpeg to transfer video data to the streaming plugin.
The Q&A shows how to do this on Raspberry Pi.
https://superuser.com/questions/1458442/h264-stream-to-janus-using-ffmpeg-on-raspberry-pi

Short summary is below.

#### Set up Janus gateway streaming plugin

The streaming plugin configuration file is `/opt/janus/etc/janus/janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg`. ([official documentation](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/streaming.html))

You can find there are several sample configurations. For example,
`rtp-sample` receives VP8/Opus video streaming data via RTP.
If you want to stream H.264 video, you can edit the configuration to add this setting.

```
h264-sample: {
        type = "rtp"
        id = 10
        description = "H.264 live stream"
        audio = false
        video = true
        videoport = 8004
        videopt = 126
        videortpmap = "H264/90000"
        videofmtp = "profile-level-id=42e01f;packetization-mode=1"
        secret = "somesecretid"
}
```

After editing the configuration, you need to restart Janus gateway.

#### Start video streaming

You can send video data to Janus streaming plugin via RTP. For example, if you have FFMpeg, you can do like this.

```
$ ffmpeg \
    -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 8192 -input_format yuyv422 \
    -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 10 -i /dev/video0 \
    -c:v h264_omx -profile:v baseline -b:v 1M -bf 0 \
    -flags:v +global_header -bsf:v "dump_extra=freq=keyframe" \
    -max_delay 0 -an -bufsize 1M -vsync 1 -g 10 \
    -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:8004/
```

This command reads video data from `/dev/video0` and
Please note the video parameters and output RTP port number (`8084` in above example) should be corresponding to the Janus streaming plugin configuration.

#### Prepare Vue.js frontend

Next step is a frontend. You can create web frontend to view the streaming using [janus.js](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/html/janus.js) bundled in Janus gateway. As described in the [official documantation](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/js-modules.html), you can use the janus.js as JavaScript module. But when you want to use it from Vue.js, you will need [export-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/exports-loader/).

For example, you can create Vue.js2 project and add janus.js like this.

```
$ vue create mystreaming
$ cd mystreaming
$ yarn add git://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway.git
$ yarn add exports-loader --dev
```

To add Webpack configuration, you need to create `vue.config.js` file with following content.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ adapter: 'webrtc-adapter' })
    ],
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: require.resolve('janus-gateway'),
          loader: 'exports-loader',
          options: {
            exports: 'Janus',
          },
        }
      ]
    } 
  }
}
```

Then, you can import `Janus` object from Vue.js module like this.

```
import { Janus } from 'janus-gateway';
```

Then you can use **janus.js** and receive streaming video data using [APIs](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/JS.html).

I uploaded [example Vue.js project](https://github.com/kimurakhs/janus-vue-streaming-example), which might also help you.